# Metadata V12 / V14

Tags: json-rpc, metadata

We just migrated from *substrate v3* to *substrate v4*, after that I expected to have metadata *V14* when I'll call `state_getMetadata` rpc method.
but I still get *V12* metadata and I don't understand why.

If you have an idea..
thank you.

Comment: How did you do the upgrade? Are you testing on a live chain? Please provide more detail.

Comment: @AurevoirXavier I am testing on the local chain : https://gist.github.com/ascjones/0d81a4c44e84cacd9f714cd34a6de823 -> sounds good on our side ! maybe we need to update something else ?

Comment: Do you do the runtime upgrade for your local chain? If you are using the dev chain. I think it should work. What's your Substrate version? IIUC, If you don't make types derive from `TypeInfo` then the pallet can not be compiled. If you could compile then it should work.

Comment: This is how polkadot do the upgrade. https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/3336/files

Comment: yes, thank you, just our version  of scale-info is  `scale-info = { version = "2.0.1", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }`

Comment: @AurevoirXavier do you know how to get current metadata inside a customer rpc call ? (ok for V14 that's good !)

Comment: curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"state_metadata"}' http://127.0.0.1:9933

Comment: @AurevoirXavier yes with curl, but inside the substrate code?

Comment: Maybe you could check your `Cargo.locks`. If the `frame-metadata` version is 14.0 or 15.0.

Comment: Also this one https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/3336/files#diff-e5e76e02c0d16e79c70b024cbe3c6ea56f3249382a0f987ba203c34fcb40ed66R1284

Comment: yes version is ok now I have v14 but now I need to  get metadata inside my rpc call to be able to use that : https://github.com/paritytech/parity-signer/blob/02a7b00789698c3ab3ed65b83bc1a77f18b88071/rust/parser/src/lib.rs#L28 and decode extrinsics :-)